# The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, mapping

I am new to Java and Spring. I encountered the error trying to apply CSS styles.
Here is my jsp:

```
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:display="urn:jsptld:http://displaytag.sf.net"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<jsp:directive.page import="test1.domain.*" />

<html>
<head>
<title>CD Catalog</title>
<link href='<c:url value="/css/displaytag.css" />' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
and so on...
```

The css folder is on the same level where WEB-INF is.

In my servlet.xml I have:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/*" />
```

The next error I get:

**HTTP Status 500 - /WEB-INF/jsp/test_task.jsp(11,15) The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.**

I tried also single and double quotes the other way round, and tried the same double quotes, but it wasn't successful.

I would appreciate any advice.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: as someone who doesn't know spring but is just reading your code and your error message, looks like where you have `"href='<c:url value="/css/displaytag.css" />'"`, there is something wrong with your syntax and you should probably just have `"href=/css/displaytag.css"`

Comment: referencing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421891/how-to-create-hyperlink-in-spring-jsp maybe you should be using `c:out` instead, but if you're hardcoding it anyway it doesn't sound like you really need to.

Comment: @colleen: it seems that this is actually idiomatic code. See [this tutorial page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please add tag library declaration`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` to the header. The taglib directive declares that your JSP page uses a set of custom tags(`c:url` here), and identifies the location of the library. Without that indication, your JSP file will end up with a (`href`) attribute containing an unescaped `<` character, which is not a valid XML.

**UPDATE**:

Just realize you are using JSP document instead of JSP page, and you've already declared namespace `xmlns:c`, so taglib isn't needed any more. Since JSP document strictly requires well-formed XML document, it complains about your link's href attribute(with unescaped `<` inside). To avoid that, try:

```
<c:url var="url" value="/css/displaytag.css" />
<link href="${url}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Is that: xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" not the same as <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  ?

Comment: no, xmlns:c is namespace declaration, which is different from taglib declaration.

Comment: Could both these options be used concurrently within one JSP ?

Comment: Yes, and when I put <%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %> into my JSP right before <html> tag, having all xmlns declarations before taglib of course, I get an error:   HTTP Status 500 - /WEB-INF/jsp/test_task.jsp(7,4) The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Comment: Thank you Hui Zheng!  You really helped me.  Link, you have provided: [Creating a JSP Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPX3.html) helped me to realize the difference.